# Setting up Unmanaged ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle11g, unmanaged, odp.net

## Problem

So I have encountered an issue that in which I am working with a FIPS enforced environment and an 11g Oracle database that is having issues with using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` due to a known bug involving FIPS. This problem is further exasperated by the fact that the only known solutions are:

1. Upgrade to 12.2c (Not an option we can take)
2. Disable FIPS (Not an option we can take)
3. Convert Managed to Unmanaged (Option we are trying to pursue)

Without going into too much detail, we can't upgrade because we do not control 2 of the 3 environments, which prevent us from enforcing a consistent workspace between all three environments. We cannot disable FIPS as it is a required setting. Which leaves me back at converting Managed to Unmanaged.

Some may think this is simple, but I have little to no experience with Oracle or ODP.NET and, as such, converting the C# files, specifically those using Entity Framework, to Unmanaged is foreign to me.

I have sought out tutorials for setting it up from the ground up, but nothing I have found is for unmanaged. Nearly everything I find is typically for setting up ODP.NET and Entity Framework as managed, how to convert Unmanaged to Managed, or tidbits about unmanaged connections. There seems to be little to nothing out there now about this, or I am just looking in all the wrong places.

## Question

How can I set up ODP.NET with Entity Framework using Oracle 11g as unmanaged? Could someone give me a brief rundown on what is needed?